# Get maximum value from two values

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table which gives the no of rides by a rider at each stand point. I need to find the stand for each rider for which he has the maximum rides.

My first result is in this format: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ydo4.png)

I require my final result like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S577y.png)

I'm currently using this query, but I know it can be done in a better manner. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
select c.rider_id, c.end_stand, b.max_rides
from
    (select rider_id, max(rides) as max_rides
    from
        (select rider_id, end_stand, count(id) as rides
        from ride where end_stand is not null
        group by 1,2) a
    group by 1
    order by 2 desc, 1) b
join
    (select rider_id, end_stand, count(id) as rides
    from ride where end_stand is not null
    group by 1,2) c
on c.rider_id = b.rider_id and c.rides = b.max_rides
order by 3 desc, 2,1
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sample data pls

Comment: @BlackSwan Added snapshots to give a better sense of the data

Answer (score 1):

Before window functions, one method is a correlated subquery in the `having` clause:

```
select rider_id, end_stand, count(*) as rides
from ride r
where end_stand is not null
group by rider_id, end_stand
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from ride r2
                   where r2.end_stand is not null and
                         r2.rider_id = r.rider_id
                   group by r2.rider_id, r2.end_stand
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

With window functions, this is, of course, much simpler:

```
select *
from (select rider_id, end_stand, count(*) as rides
             rank() over (partition by rider_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from ride r
      where end_stand is not null
      group by rider_id, end_stand
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Both these will return duplicates, if there are ties for the max.  The second version is easy to fix, if you want only one row:  use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out.